# When developing Android, should I refer to API number or OS version and what is the difference?

Tags: java, android, api, operating-system

I constantly see people refer to Jelly-Bean or Ice-Cream Sandwich when talking about Android versions, but what confuses me is that Android Studio and Eclipse almost exclusively refer to API versions. When I try to match up API versions with Android OS releases, they don't seem to happen at the same time. What is the difference between the two and if using an API specific class, should I refer to it by API or OS version?

Comment: See the first table in this article: https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: If it was, I made an explanatory answer to save the others time, make it clearer if it's needed and on the other hand to let the others see that your question is already answered... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the first table in [this article](http://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html), it lists which codename(s) belong(s) to which api version.
The [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) might have more useful infos about codenames...
A bit explanation:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
  // only if os version is Gingerbread (Android 2.3) or newer
}
```

Based on [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) article, the code above equals to the one below:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
  // only if os version is Gingerbread (Android 2.3) or newer
}
```

Also from the last article you can see: you can use api version numbers as codenames too. Which one is easier to learn, it's up to you... :)